# Power on/off jetson xavier nx in a proper way

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

It seems to me like power on and off have two different behaviours:

1. if I shutdown jetson xavier nx through the operating system and after that turns off the power, jetson xavier wont start when I turn the power back on. First I have to remove the powerplug from the device and reinsert it again.
2. if I just turns off the power and in that way are closing jetson xavier it will restart as soon as I turn the power on again.

While number two works it seems always better to turn off the operating system first but it is a bit odd to remove and reinsert the cable to restart it.

What is the proper way of doing this? Or does number two nothing to worry about? Or am I better off install some kind of on off switch or what is the most easy way of handle this fundamental thing?

Answer (score 0):

It only works in these three scenarios:

cutting the powersupply - the jetson starts when it is back on
shutting down from menu - the jetson starts if I remove and reconnect the powerplug to the jetson
shutting down from menu - the jetson starts if I wait 5-10 minutes before I start the electricity again